# Сколько примерно времени работает парсер

Tags: парсер

Кто делал парсер? подскажите пожалуйста сколько времени нужно чтобы спарсить 40 000 товаров примерно

Comment: Необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса!
Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: ну незнаю как развернуто написать, сколько обычно времени занимает парсинг 40 000 товаров которые находятся в другом сайте, пример кода ни причем интерсно знать скорость работы как у всех или нет

Comment: Зависит от системы, когда и объёмов парсинга, но думаю секунд 10

Comment: @misha11, так Вам тогда на другой сайт, сайт опросов :)

Comment: 4 5 секунд за каждую запись это очень долго да?

Comment: 10 секунд за все 40 000 или же для одной записи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть много нюансов, поэтому ответ абстрактный.

1. Во сколько потоков парсить? Чем больше воркеров, тем быстрее они
   спарсят 40к товаров. Если запросов будет слишком много, можем
   положить сервер или получить бан.
2. Сколько времени сервер отвечает? Зависит от performance сервера и его физического местоположения и местоположения парсеров.
3. Банит ли сервер? Будем посылать прямые запросы или парсить через
   proxy? Наверняка бегать через proxy будет медленнее.
4. Иногда запросы будут отваливаться, поэтому будут нужны дополнительные попытки.

Предположим, что сервер нормально держит нагрузку в 50 потоков, не банит и отвечает в среднем за 4с. Тогда 40000 * 4 / 50 = 3200 cек. Грубо говоря, один час.

Comment: спасибо за содержательный ответ,!

Answer (score 2):

Есть вариант посчитать приблизительно

```
time curl "http://url/of/one/item.html"
```

Таким образом Вы получите время обработки одного объекта, который Вы забираете себе.

с помощью утилиты siege - Вы можете проверить на сколько объектов Вы можете расчитывать, точнее сколько объектов отдаст сервер-источник  в секунду.

Comment: парсит примерно от 2 секунд до 5 6 это как то не так написано или все так долго происходит?

Comment: Это , по-сути, нормально.
Далее, понимайте такой момент, что когда Вы нагружаете во много потоков Ваш парсер, то нужно следить за временем ответа сервера источника: если оно меняется в большую сторону, то следует сокращать кол-во потоков пока увелечение времени ответа не прекратиться

Comment: ну мне кажется что этот прасер написан неправильно, потоков нет, работает все из одного скрипта, но еще непонятна такая вещь, если на пхп написать обращение к каким то обьектам чтобы они запускались и парсили данные (некое подобие многопоточности), и сделать это через внутренний прокси айпи то при обращении с сервера на нужный ресурс тот хост же зачтет эти обращения с внешнего айпи и это будет похоже на ддос ну в любом случае скорее всего заблокируют доступ или прокси как то иначе работают?